# The ide dev-c++ gives me an error and i have no clue what is it about

Tags: c++

when i try to use the function malloc and i literally write this

```
float *p=malloc(sizeof(float));
```

it detect an Error that sais

> Invalid conversion from 'void' to 'float'

Comment: C++ requires an explicit cast to convert `void*` to `float*`. C doesn't.

Comment: If you're going to write C++ code you should learn to use `new` or avoid dynamic allocation with raw pointers and use `std::vector`.